# Converting a string timestamp HH:MM:SS to an integer in C

Tags: c, string, timestamp, atoi

Forgive me for my naivety I'm just learning C for the first time. Basically I have a series of strings that contain a timestamp in the format "HH:MM:SS". I'm looking to write a function of the form int tsconvert(char *) that can covert the timestamp to an integer. Here is some code I've written so far

```
int tsconvert(char *timestamp)
{
    int x;
    removeColon(timestamp,8);
    x = atoi(timestamp);
    return x; 
}

void removeColon(char *str1, int len)    
{
    int j = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        if (str1[i] == ':')
        {
            continue;
        }

        else
        {
            str1[j] = str1[i];
            j++;
        }
    }

    str1[j] = '\0';
}
```

When I try and use this code however I get a segmentation error. Some one in my programing class suggested that I simply extract the numbers from the timestamp and place those in a new string but I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: How do you actually call this `tsconvert()`?

Comment: @leeduhem This is my full program the segmentaion error is occurring because of the call in line 115 [link](http://pastebin.com/n5nFjHkL).

Comment: I cannot open your link, maybe it is blocked by GFW.

Comment: @leeduhem Haha sorry try this http://pastebin.com/n5nFjHkL

Comment: Still no luck. Maybe the entire site has been blocked.

Comment: @leeduhem http://hastebin.com/tedewifuwi.coffee heres a different site, thank you for trying to help though.

Comment: hastebin.com is blocked by GFW too. You could post your code to www.dropbox.com, looks like this works for me.

Comment: Or http://pastebin.ca/, this one also works, FOR NOW.

Comment: @leeduhem http://pastebin.ca/2653742

Comment: Please post the whole source, some crucial parts, such as the implementation of `allocate()`, are missing.

Comment: @leeduhem http://pastebin.ca/2653755 Sorry I've updated it and included scanner.c it's a library of functions created by my professor that he has us use. There shouldn't be any problem with the scanner.c functions themselves.

Comment: Could you offer any sample input files?

Comment: Add `if (type == EOF) return 0;` after `type = readChar(fp);` in your `readLog()`, and try again.

Comment: @leeduhem It worked thank you!!! What exactly was the issue if you don't mind me asking. Also it probably to late but I added sample input http://pastebin.ca/2653868.

Comment: When `readChar(fp)` returns an EOF, which means `fp` reaches its end; in this case, `readToken(fp)` will return a NULL pointer; and when you pass this NULL pointer to `tsconvert()`, `sscanf()` will try to parse the string pointed to by a NULL, this will crash your program. That is why you see the crash happened at `tsconvert()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To extract the numbers from the timestamp (HH:MM:SS), just use sscanf():

```
const char *str = "01:02:03";
int h, m, s;
sscanf(str, "%d:%d:%d", &h, &m, &s);
printf ("%d, %d, %d\n", h, m, s);
```

Comment: Well your function worked, but when I try to use it in my program I still get a segmentation fault.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is not much different than [@Younggun Kim](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22315158/2410359) but with recommended additional error checking.

Use `"%n"` to determine if scanning completed to the end of the string with no additional junk.

```
// -1 error else 0 - 86399
long tsconvert(const char *timestam) {
  unsigned h, m, s;
  int n = 0;
  int cnt = sscanf(timestam, "%2u:%2u:%2u %n", &h, &m, &s, &n);
  if (cnt != 3 || timestam[n] != '\0') return -1 ; // Format Error;
  if (h >= 24 || m >= 60 || s >= 60) return -1; // Range Error
  // 0 - 86400-1
  return ((h*60 + m)*60L + s;
}
```